# Android Gesture Recognition multiple events

Tags: java, android, gesture-recognition

In my application I have a `VideoView` that display a video feed coming from a camera pool. I wish to use gesture recognition to *change* which camera is being shown.
Scrolling on X axis should change camera type, scrolling on Y axis should switch the *side* of the camera group.

Source (of the `MainActivity` object where the `VideoView` is located):

```
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new CameraGestureListener());

    cameraView = findViewById(R.id.cameraView);

    cameraView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent))
                return true;

            return MainActivity.super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    });
```

And finally I defined this class (inside `MainActivity`):

```
class CameraGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "onDown: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if(Math.abs(velocityY)>Math.abs(velocityX))
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "change side");
        }
        else if(velocityX>0)
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "change camera type");
        }
        else if(velocityX<0)
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "change camera type");
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if(Math.abs(distanceY)>Math.abs(distanceX))
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "change side");
        }
        else if(distanceX>0)
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "change camera type");
        }
        else if(distanceX<0)
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "change camera type");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

In debug I can clearly see that `Scroll` events are triggered twice and often **distanceX** is larger than **distanceY** even if the gesture is mainly on the physical Y screen axis. Same problems arise with similar behaviours on `Fling` events.
How can I fix this?

Comment: what does `return MainActivity.super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);` do inside `View.OnTouchListener#onTouch` method? just return `true` from it

Comment: @pskink it's works! ... `onSling` event now correctly reports the action I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: good, nice to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Following pskink suggestion the only needed fix was to remove the unneeded retrigger of the superclass event handler (a cut&paste misprint of my own):

```
MainActivity.super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

The correct code become:

```
cameraView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

        return true;
    }
});
```

The gesture is properly recognized by `onFling` event handler. Trough `onScroll` event handlers you still observe two events for each gesture but it's probably a correct behaviour.